# Get google cloud uptime history to a third party application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, health-monitoring, google-cloud-monitoring

I am trying to get my application(where hosted in google cloud) uptime history to a my own page. Is there any api so something on google cloud? I only need to get date and the up/down percentage or time.

I am already configure the uptime checks on google console. But I need to integrate this into my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can but it's not obvious and it may be easier to use something other than Cloud Monitoring to export uptime data to a non-GCP site :-)

If you do want to use Cloud Monitoring to source this data into an off-GCP page, one of the Cloud Monitoring [SDKs](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/reference/libraries) may be best. You can create a URL too (see below) but you'll need to authenticate this URL and that may make it too complex.

By way of an example, here's an Uptime check I created against my blog:

[image]

I recommend [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) as it's an excellent way to understand Google's services (via the REST APIs) and to test an approach.

First: List|Get Uptime Check(s)

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.uptimeCheckConfigs/list

Plug in to the form on the right hand side `parent`, the value of `projects/${PROJECT}`

If your Project ID is `freddie-210224-66311747` then you'd type `project/freddie-210224-66311747`.

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.uptimeCheckConfigs/get

For this one, you need to provide `name`, the value of `projects/${PROJECT}/uptimeCheckConfigs/${UPTIME_CHECK}`

If your Uptime check is called `test`, then you'd type `projects/freddie-210224-66311747/uptimeCheckConfigs/test`

> **NOTE** In my case, I used an Uptime check name that included periods (`my.blog.com`) and this was converted (to `my-blog-com`). So, you may want to list first to check the name.

Click "Execute" (You don't need to have `API Key` checked but it makes no difference).

What I learned is that Uptime checks are Metrics like all others. I confirmed this by watching the Chrome Dev Tools while I was watching Uptime checks.

Ensure that you use the correct metric name. You can use Monitoring's Metrics Explorer to confirm this:

[image]

The Resource Type is `Uptime Check URL` (`uptime_url`)

One (!) of the Metrics you may use is `Request Latency` (`monitoring.googleapis.com/uptime_check/request_latency`)

If you populate the Metrics Explorer, you should see the same data plotted as with the Uptime Check page.

Click `Query Editor` to get your Uptime Metric represented as Cloud Monitoring Query Language (MQL), remove any line-feeds. You can use:

`fetch uptime_url | metric 'monitoring.googleapis.com/uptime_check/request_latency' | group_by 1m, [value_request_latency_mean: mean(value.request_latency)] | every 1m`

So, now we want to query Montioring Metric Time-series

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/query

The value for `name` is `projects/${PROJECT}`

For `query`, paste in the MQL from above retain the quotes, i.e. `"fetch uptime_url ..."`

Hit `EXECUTE`

You should receive a snapshot of the time-series data underlying your Uptime URL. You can revise the MQL to reflect exactly the subset that you need. At `2021-02-24T20:55:38` the latency was `20.869`:

[image]

So, to get e.g. request latencies for your uptime checks, you can use the Monitoring API's TimeSeries Query  method and, with a suitable Query, this will yield JSON data including an array of Point (values). These values could then be transformed and surfaced into your external page.