# Uptime in GCP: Measure the % uptime where site is available from _any_ location

Tags: uptime, uptime-monitoring

Our site is running on Google App Engine, and we've set up monitoring and uptime alerts.

We want to be able to report on site uptime as a %, where the site is consider up if it can be accessed from any of the 6 locations:

- If location A cannot access the site, but locations B, C, D, E and F can. The site is up.
- If locations A, B, C, D and E cannot access the site, but location F can. The site is up.
- If locations A, B, C, D, E and F cannot access the site. The site is down.

Currently the % calculation is: (1 - Total number of failed checks) / (Total number of checks). This unfortunately means that the uptime is affected by a single location being unable to access the site.

Is it possible to get the uptime calculation we're after?

Comment: Does creating an uptime check from multiple regions not help? https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks/

Comment: Unfortunately not @dishantmakwana — that's what we have currently, and it leads to the % calculation described above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get google cloud uptime history to a third party application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66311747/get-google-cloud-uptime-history-to-a-third-party-application)

Comment: Unfortunately not — that post just talks about integrating an uptime check into your own app @Sergiusz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an [uptime chart](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/uptime-charts) for that.
If you group data by app, and set aggregator to `fraction true`, then graph will reach zero only when all of the uptime checks fail.
Query will look something like that (this is for VM instance):

```
fetch gce_instance
| metric 'monitoring.googleapis.com/uptime_check/check_passed'
| filter (metric.check_id == 'uptime-1')
| group_by 1m, [value_check_passed_count_true: count_true(value.check_passed)]
| every 1m
```

Comment: That seems to do it — thank you! I wasn't clear on how "fraction true" worked :)